# GCP Livestream API status update callback

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, live-streaming

I am using Google Livestream API for transcoding using RTMP protocol. There are few status from the GCP end. For example, Started, Stopped, Streaming, etc...

I need to know the status of channel(livestream). I can do that by using the API call. But I need to call the API everytime user want to see OR using a schedular to pull data from GCP.

So, My question is,
**Is there any hook/pub-sub anything that only I can know when status is changed?**

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Mohammad Ashraful, As per this official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/streaming/live-streaming), Livestreaming API is in Beta version, i.e., it is in Pre GA offerings with limited support. So, I suggest you create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/), if you have a support plan please. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.